# How to pass values through a redirect?

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

Nice to be here!

I'd really appreciate some help on this issue - I run a domain search site, and am building some links that forward the customer onto GoDaddy or whoever to purchase the domain.

Currently my affiliate links look like:

http://www.dpbolvw.net/interactive?domainToCheck={domainname}&tld={tld}&checkAvail=1&pid=xxxxxx&url=http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/registrar/search.asp?isc=cjc695tnw&aid=xxxxxx&sid=click_godaddy_com

But I would like them to just look like www.mysite.com/BuyFromGodaddy

From my research, it would seem a PHP redirect would be the best way to do this. I have googled this extensively, but all of the articles seem to talk about a static redirect - ie. www.mysite.com/link1 will always go to www.othersite.com/page1

Instead, I need to pass the domain name they want to buy through the redirect, otheriwse when the user is forwarded to GoDaddy's site, they would have to type their search in all over again.

Could anyone help with this at all?

Many thanks,

Pierre

Comment: When you see using PHP do you mean header("Location: http://www...");  ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly, currently you have an affiliate URL that contains several parameters in the query string and instead you want the link to be much shorter and "prettier"?

If so, you might want to make the link something like: http://www.mysite.com/BuyFromGoDaddy/domaintobuy.com

You can then redirect from that URL to GoDaddy.com passing the domain name (e.g., domaintobuy.com) along with anything that GoDaddy needs to identify your affiliate ID. You can achieve this with a temporary redirect (e.g., 302 or 303).

Would that work for your needs?